# PayPal API Order Request in Kotlin using Android SDK

Tags: kotlin, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

According to paypal's documentation you can pay orders and something like that but I don't know if it's possible to send this kind of request using Android SDK (link below):

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-H "PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id: EXAMPLE_MP" \
-d '{
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "store_mobile_world_order_1234",
      "description": "Mobile World Store order-1234",
      "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "1.09",
          "shipping": "0.02",
          "tax": "0.33"
        },
        "total": "1.44"
      },
      "payee": {
        "email": "seller@example.com"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "NeoPhone",
          "sku": "sku03",
          "price": "0.54",
          "currency": "USD",
          "quantity": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Fitness Watch",
          "sku": "sku04",
          "price": "0.55",
          "currency": "USD",
          "quantity": "1"
        }
      ],
      "shipping_address": {
        "line1": "2211 N First Street",
        "line2": "Building 17",
        "city": "San Jose",
        "country_code": "US",
        "postal_code": "95131",
        "state": "CA",
        "phone": "(123) 456-7890"
      },
      "shipping_method": "United Postal Service",
      "partner_fee_details": {
        "receiver": {
          "email": "partner@example.com"
        },
        "amount": {
          "value": "0.01",
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      "payment_linked_group": 1,
      "custom": "custom_value_2388",
      "invoice_number": "invoice_number_2388",
      "payment_descriptor": "Payment Mobile World"
    }
  ],
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
    "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
  }
}'
```

Ps. It seems like `getStuffToBuy()` (line 83) could make this request but I'm not really sure if it's possible to make it

```
 purchase_units: [
                {
                  reference_id: another field,
                  description: 'Hello World',
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: 'MXN',
                    value: "100.00"
                  }
                }
              ]
```

Android SDK:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp-Kotlin/src/main/java/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.kt

PayPal's Documentation:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) is deprecated and will be end of life [December 2020]

### Original answer

If you want a native SDK for processing PayPal payments, use [Express Checkout via the Braintree SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/)

For authentication, use a sandbox **access token** from the bottom of  https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications on your server, and return a client token to your client.  (production access token, https://www.paypal.com/api )

Do not create a Braintree gateway account, nor use gateway credentials from braintreegateway.com .  Do not use a tokenization key.

### Update March 2021

Native Checkout is now available in some countries, notably US and Europe: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/

---

For non-native payments, the orders v1 documentation you linked to should also not be used.  Use orders v2, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/